# Spring CXF Client Test

Tags: spring, cxf

I am working on sending a request to a web service and parsing the response.  I have to use Spring 3 and Apache CXF. Using Maven's wsdl2java, I was able to generate request and response objects from the wsdl. These classes have been generated now and I see basically what appear to be annotated POJO's. I am unclear what the next step is to actually send the request to the web services. All I see is an ObjectFactory to create the initial web service.

What is the next step? Do I need to create a spring bean configuration file like this?

```
<jaxws:client id="XXXX"
              serviceClass="XXXX"
              address="http://localhost:8080/xxxx />
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciates as I am not sure how to send the actual request to the web or what my next step would be. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to look the webservice without using spring you can use the stubs generated & make a call to the service in a program with main. Something like..

http://61.153.44.88/apache/cxf/2.0/developing-a-consumer.html

If you want to use spring, see  "Create a Client" section here

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/writing-a-service-with-spring.html

Answer (score 2):

There is a post [here](http://blog.jeshurun.ca/technology/jax-ws-web-services-with-spring-and-cxf) with an example of how to create a CXF Client and server and integrate it with Spring.